# scrab urls from web page using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

this my code so far

```
 foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox_google_urls.Items)
        {              
            var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(listBoxItem.ToString());
            var files = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", ".mp3")).Where(h => h.Contains(".mp3")).ToArray(); 
            listbox_urls.Items.AddRange(files);
        }
```

and this where come listBox_google_urls.Items

```
 web_search.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + val + "+(mp3|wav|ac3|ogg|flac|wma|m4a) -inurl:(jsp|pl|php|html|aspx|htm|cf|shtml) intitle:index.of -inurl:(listen77|mp3raid|mp3toss|mp3drug|index_of|wallywashis)");
        var search_results = this.web_search.Document.Links.Cast<HtmlElement>().Select(a => a.GetAttribute("href")).Where(h => h.Contains("http://")).ToArray();
        listBox_google_urls.Items.AddRange(search_results);
```

listBoxItem.ToString() output [example](http://s1.mymrmusic2.com/hmusic/Album/Foreign%20Albums/VA%20-%20Billboard%20Hot%20100%20(02%20April%202016)/VA%20-%20Billboard%20Hot%20100%20(02%20April%202016)%20%5B320%5D/)

the problem is this méthode work but only scrab  titles of links only 
they are way how i can fix it ?? and thanks already

Comment: can you post an example of what the listBoxItem.ToString() output is? Will make it much easier to help you out

Comment: @MarkRedfern i edit you can check it

Comment: Are you trying to get the link text or the link URL?

Comment: links of urls  like this i wanna extract  all urls on web page are like this http://78.140.251.40/tmp_audio/top100/rr/001%20MATT%20NASH%20-%20Know%20My%20Love.mp3     @MarkRedfern

Answer (score 1):

your code looks good, just not sure why you are defaulting to ".mp3" and then returning all that have ".mp3" ? you gonna end up with a collection of valid .mp3 URL's and then a whole bunch of ".mp3" strings? I just hoocked into a rando google search page and looked for all url's with the word "mail" in the href attribute, here are the results

[image]

Hope this answers your question. If you can give me some more info, maybe I could help a little more

Try this

```
        var document = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://s1.mymrmusic2.com/hmusic/Album/Foreign%20Albums/VA%20-%20Billboard%20Hot%20100%20(02%20April%202016)/VA%20-%20Billboard%20Hot%20100%20(02%20April%202016)%20%5B320%5D/");
        var files = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
            .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty)) && a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty).Contains(".mp3"))
            .Select(a => new
            {
                Link = a.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty),
                Text = a.FirstChild.InnerText
            }).ToList();
```

[image]

Maybe try this option

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox_google_urls.Items)
        {
            var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(listBoxItem.ToString());
            var files = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
                .Select(a => a.GetAttributeValue("href", ".mp3"))
                .Where(h => h.Contains(".mp3"))
                .Select(a => listBoxItem.ToString() + a).ToArray();
            listbox_urls.Items.AddRange(files);
        }
```

Comment: this dont solve the problem but thanks for your helping

Comment: @AdamKim - is that what you were after? check the edited answer

Comment: thats whats i get exactly with my code i wanna get those urls like this http://s1.mymrmusic2.com/hmusic/Album/Foreign%20Albums/VA%20-%20Billboard%20Hot%20100%20(02%20April%202016)/VA%20-%20Billboard%20Hot%20100%20(02%20April%202016)%20%5B320%5D/029-Chris%20Brown%20-%20Back%20To%20Sleep.mp3                                  not titles of them and sorry for the missunderstanding